# How to create simple webhooks for asana

Tags: node.js, asana

I'm new to asana API and need help in creating webhooks to track activities in asana. a simple example using NodeJS would be fine. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: https://github.com/Asana/node-asana

A JavaScript client (for both Node and browser) for the Asana API v1.0.

Install with npm:

```
npm install asana --save
```

Browser
Include the latest release directly from GitHub.

```
<script src="https://github.com/Asana/node-asana/releases/download/<LATEST_RELEASE>/asana-min.js"></script>
```

OR

Download the latest distribution in releases.
Make sure to serve it from your webserver.
Include it on the client from a SCRIPT tag.

Usage
To do anything, you'll need always an instance of an Asana.Client configured with your preferred authentication method and other options.

The most minimal example would be as follows:

```
const asana = require('asana');
const client = asana.Client.create().useAccessToken('my_access_token');
client.users.me().then(function(me) {
  console.log(me);
});
```

Comment: thank you very much... I tried out that .. is there a way to register and use a webhook with this?

Comment: @BhashithaHemantha You can find an example of a node app that creates a webhook and prints out events here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/asana-webhooks

Comment: @BhashithaHemantha Glad to help you. If this helped you, Could you please mark the answer as useful. Thank you

Comment: is there an example which uses lambda functions in aws with these.

Comment: i'm trying to register a webhook to asana and trigger an endpoint in aws lambda with it... would that be possible and is there any examples..

Comment: @BhashithaHemantha I think this is what you are looking for. https://zapier.com/apps/asana/integrations/aws-lambda. But this is a paid version even though you can enjoy trial for 14 days.

Good to look https://forum.asana.com/t/open-source-real-time-starting-point-application-for-asana-via-webhooks/1799

Comment: @BhashithaHemantha 
This example will give you an insight: https://github.com/mtsvickers/td-aws-asana